Neumann Boundary value problem $u_{xx} + \lambda u = 0$
Consider $$u_{xx} + \lambda u = 0$$
with boundary conditions $-\partial_{x}u(0)=i\omega\alpha u(0)$ and $\partial_x u(1)  = 0$,
where $\lambda := \omega^2$ and $\alpha$ is a real constant.
I am trying to find an analytical solution. In my attempt, I consider a solution of the form $$u = c_1 \cos(\omega x) + c_2 \sin(\omega x)$$
Substituting into the equation yields \begin{equation}2\lambda (c_1 \cos(\omega x) + c_2 \sin(\omega x)) = 0\end{equation}
From the boundary conditions:
the left one gives $c_2 = i\alpha c_1$ and the right one gives $c_1 ( \cos(\omega) + i\alpha \sin(\omega)) = 0$
but from this, I think we conclude $c_1 =0 \implies c_2 = 0 \implies u = 0$. Is there a non-trivial solution?
